# Defining a custom key name to selected columns from results returned in Eloquent

Tags: mysql, sqlite, eloquent

I have an Eloquent scope search query like this that takes in input parameters like this:

```
"ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lab",
"ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lecture",
"ECEC 302 Digital Systems Projects Lab",
"ECEC 471 Introduction to VLSI Design Lab"
```

Using this Model:

```
public function scopeSearchWithType($query, $searchTerm) {
    return $query->where(
        DB::raw("subject_code || ' ' ||  course_no || ' ' || course_title || ' ' || instr_type"),
        'like',
        '%' . $searchTerm . '%'
    )->select(
        $searchTerm,
        'day',
        'time',
        'crn'
    );
}
```

As you can see, each input string is actually the combination of four different columns.

Anyways. When I run this query, this is the following result:

```
       "ECEC 471 Introduction to VLSI Design Lab": "ECEC 471 Introduction to VLSI Design Lab",
       day: "W",
       time: "09:00 am - 10:50 am",
       crn: "12506"
   }
```

As you can see, the key of `$searchQuery` is the name of the `value`. I would like to assign a custom name such as `course_name` to the key.

I've tried everything from `class => $searchTerm` to `class as $searchTerm`, but they did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in an array into the `$value` of the scope query. This will allow you to define a `$search['term']` and a `$search['column']` so you can rename the column dynamically.

```
public function scopeSearchWithType($query, $search) {
    return $query->where(
        DB::raw("subject_code || ' ' ||  course_no || ' ' || course_title || ' ' || instr_type"),
        'like',
        '%' . $search['term'] . '%'
    )->select(
        $search['column'] . 'as' . $search['term'],
        'day',
        'time',
        'crn'
    );
}
```

However, I should mention that you're not going to be able to end your Eloquent query because the `QueryBuilder` object needs to be returned in Query Scopes. In this example you're returning an array. You will not be able to chain methods on top of this scope query again, just a forewarning.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually what I am looking for. Could you provide a better example?

Comment: Edited my answer, putting code in comments is rough.